# Hit a curb, the curb cut off a piece of the tire. Will it needs replacement?

Tags: tires, car, repair, audi, sidewall-damage

I miscalculated the distance and hit a curb while U turning a few days ago, the curb cut off a small piece of the right front tire and scratched the wheel a little bit.

I went to a tire shop one day later to see if it needs to be replaced and the mechanic took a brief look and told me it's fine (which I'm honestly surprised they didn't take every possible opportunities to sell a tire).

But I'm still a little bit concerned and I don't really know too much about cars, so I want to get a second opinion here. Do I need to get this tire replaced or I can just use some rubber cement to seal it off?

My car is a leased 2018 audi FWD and it only has 1800 miles on it, here are some pictures to show the damage.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your photo showing the slice peeled back displays only "clear" rubber, no ply or cord and no damage deeper than the slice. The mechanic who suggested that it's okay is likely more correct than a sales tech who wants your money.

Rubber is unlike metal in that cracks/slices propagate unless other forces are applied. If your speed becomes such that the loose portion of the slice begins to flap, it may eventually break off, but will not go deeper into the rubber.

If you would like an indicator of "no problem," consider to spray the newly-exposed area with a contrasting paint that will adhere to rubber. Mask off the other areas of the tire when applying the paint. Each time you check your air pressure (monthly?) peel back the flap and you can see if the damage is increasing. It's unlikely you will see much change beyond fading paint.

Comment: I agree with Fred and it looks like that tire has the extra protection ie slightly thicker sidewall designed to protect the rims a bit...

Comment: I was looking through and seen this article you would have thought that I wrote it the same exact thing happened to me thanks for the professional input.